# GIT_ASKPASS with user and password

Tags: bash, git, credentials

I am working in a Docker container with `git --version` 2.20.1, the base image is Debian 10. I would like to clone a git repository through HTTPS using `GIT_ASKPASS` or even better the configuration property `core.askpass`. Here is what I tried:

```
GIT_ASKPASS=$(mktemp) && chmod a+rx $GIT_ASKPASS && export GIT_ASKPASS
cat > $GIT_ASKPASS <<< '#!/bin/bash
    exec printf "$JENKINS_CREDENTIALS_USR\n$JENKINS_CREDENTIALS_PSW\n"
'
```

Originally I was running it in Jenkins, but I saw that I am able to reproduce the same issue in a simple docker container. `$JENKINS_CREDENTIALS_USR` and `$JENKINS_CREDENTIALS_PSW` are defined like this:

```
JENKINS_CREDENTIALS_USR=myuser
JENKINS_CREDENTIALS_PSW=mypass
export JENKINS_CREDENTIALS_USR
export JENKINS_CREDENTIALS_PSW
```

I have not any global configuration property set. `~/.git-credentials` does not exist. The error is:

```
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://myserver.com/git/project.git/'
```

---

It works by specifying the username in the HTTPS url, like this

```
git clone https://jenkins@myserver.com/git/project.git .
```

and printing the password only in the script pointed by `GIT_ASKPASS`, so I am wondering why it does not work without the username in the url. The [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials#_requesting_credentials) clearly says that

> If the `GIT_ASKPASS` environment variable is set, the program specified by the variable is invoked. **A suitable prompt is provided to the program on the command line, and the user's input is read from its standard output**.

Because when I try to clone, I am asked for both username and password, what is wrong with the original `GIT_ASKPASS` script?

Comment: `exec printf` does it work without `exec`?

Comment: I tried that too but still not working. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-56897#comment-364399). All credits go to @AlexeyPelykh, I just adapted his script.

---

When trying to `git clone`, our shell script is called once for each prompted line, basically:

```
$GIT_ASKPASS "Username for ..."
$GIT_ASKPASS "Password for ..."
```

The problem in my original script is that it returns both the username and password independently from what I am asked for. That is also the reason why in the second case (with the username specified in the URL), it works, in fact I just need the password and it returns only that.

This is how I changed my original script to make it work with `GIT_ASKPASS`:

```
GIT_ASKPASS=$(mktemp) && chmod a+rx $GIT_ASKPASS && export GIT_ASKPASS
cat > $GIT_ASKPASS <<< '#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
    Username*) exec echo "$JENKINS_CREDENTIALS_USR" ;;
    Password*) exec echo "$JENKINS_CREDENTIALS_PSW" ;;
esac
'
```

In case you want to use the configuration variable `core.askPass`, replace the first  two line with these ones:

```
git_askPass_script=$(mktemp) && chmod a+rx $git_askPass_script
cat > $git_askPass_script <<< '#!/bin/bash
```

And set the configuration variable with:

```
git config --global core.askPass "$git_askPass_script"
```

Or even better

```
git -c core.askPass="$git_askPass_script" clone ...
```